# Mechanize / Nokogiri failing to parse XML with xpath

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri, mechanize

I receive an xml file from an API. 
I'm trying to parse it with Mechanize which receives it as an XML file. 
Underlying that is Nokogiri. 
Whatever I do I can't seem to get it to return anything with any xpath variables. 
It seems to recognise the xml file fine i.e it comes in as Mechanize::XmlFile and shows the elements if I use Nokogiri.

I can run.

```
xml.at("/")
```

and get a response, but any other .at or .search I run returns nil.
e.g.

```
xml.at("//Duration")
```

An example response is below.

```
@body =
"<JobSearchResults xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.aspiremediagroup.net/jobboard/1.0/Beta\"><Duration>P0DT0H0M0.328S</Duration><JobCount>0</JobCount><JobIDs /><Jobs /><PageCount>0</PageCount><PageNo>0</PageNo><PageSize>20</PageSize><ProximityStats i:nil=\"true\" /><RoleSuggestions><String>ADDING</String></RoleSuggestions><Search><AccountGroupIDs i:nil=\"true\" /><AccountIDs i:nil=\"true\" /><ExcludeUnknownSalaries>false</ExcludeUnknownSalaries><Industries i:nil=\"true\" /><JobIDsOnly>false</JobIDsOnly><JobTypes><ID>Any</ID></JobTypes><Locations><Location><Country>GBR</Country><ID i:nil=\"true\" /><Latitude i:nil=\"true\" /><Longitude i:nil=\"true\" /><ParentLocation i:nil=\"true\" /><Text i:nil=\"true\" /></Location></Locations><MaxAge i:nil=\"true\" /><MaxDistance>25</MaxDistance><Page>1</Page><PageSize>20</PageSize><Role>adgqeg</Role><Salaries i:nil=\"true\" /><Skills i:nil=\"true\" /><SortOrder>OVERALL_SCORE_DESC</SortOrder></Search><SkillsSuggestions><String i:nil=\"true\" /></SkillsSuggestions><Started>2016-06-29T08:53:18.2215898Z</Started><ThisPageSize>0</ThisPageSize></JobSearchResults>"
```

Any ideas why that's not working?

Comment: `doc.at('Search/Locations')` and `doc.at('Duration')` both work for me. What exactly you fail to retrieve with `at`?

Comment: Interesting...
I'm searching "//Duration" and getting nothing.. but you're correct "Duration" works.

Comment: Are you using Mechanize to parse XML? It's designed to work with HTML, if you are, just use Nokogiri by itself. Also, please read "[mcve]". We need the smallest example of the XML input that demonstrates the problem, plus your minimum code that demonstrates the problem and your expected output.

Comment: Yes, I'm using mechanize to parse XML. I'm also using it to parse HTML where the structures and the outputs are similar. I could of course write a completely separate process for XML but it seemed that the two should have been straightforward enough. As it happens I found a solution that didn't require a ton of duplicated code and utilised Mechanize for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like running

```
xml.remove_namespaces!
```

fixes the issue and allows search of the document using // style xpath variables.

I suspect there's a better solution than that out there.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the .css option:

```
xml.css("Duration")
```

One could also use:

```
xml.at_css("Duration")
```

More information can be found here: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing things that are a little more complicated than css can deal with (the above is just a simplified example).